# Can I play a video file if I don't want to use MediaPlayer and VideoView?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-mediacodec

I am a newbie on Android development. I wanna quickly to know, in principle, if I can use Media Codec and OpenGL ES to playing a video file? There is no need to think about audio issue. If yes, then I can spent more time to study it. Any suggestions welcome, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup! This is essentially what [ExoPlayer](https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/guide.html) does.